# How to set the TTntRichEdit codepage

Tags: unicode, delphi-7, codepages

Is there any way to set the codepage of the TTntRichEdit component programatically to unicode? Because the default is the codepage of the system. But in this case I have not just to use the codepage stored in the RTF header but it could be modified by the \lang controls placed anywhere in the contents.
But if I could set something in the richedit control to export the characters (with codes exceed the ANSI boundaries) in \uXXXX format instead of \'XX then it wold be a charm to process the RTF contents. The RTF specification contains this type of coding. But I never get this format (\uXXXX). Just the codepage dependent (\`XX) one.

Comment: That makes no sense at all. RTF uses ASCII and any non-ASCII characters are escaped. If you want ANSI encoded text you've got the wrong control. If that's what you want, take the text content of the control and convert to your desired ANSI code page.

Comment: @David Heffernan I don't want to bother with codepages and language codes to process the rtf content. Just unicode codes for special characters like diameter sign, sqare, etc.

Comment: The format that is convenient to you isn't going to influence what RTF is. You don't get to change RTF. You have to go along with it.

Comment: RTF is an ASCII based format, you can't change that. But you can assign an ASCII string to a Unicode string, but that is not going to decode any escaped Unicode characters, you would have to do that manually.

Comment: @David Heffernan I have modified the question to explain my problem more clear.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau  I have modified the question to explain my problem more clear.

Comment: @TheBitman: `TTntRichEdit` is just a wrapper for the Win32 RichEdit v2.0+ control, which has no option to retrieve RTF using `\uXXXX` sequences instead of `\'XX` sequences. You will have to retrieve the plain Unicode text and manually create your own RTF.